# What will the bundle identifiers of the targets become when distributed via Mac App Store?

Tags: mac-app-store, bundle-identifier

I am trying to submit a Mac app to the App Store.

It includes multiple targets communicating via XPC. Therefore I need to hardwire their bundle identifiers in the code.

I found that Apple will add a prefix to the app's bundle identifier.

My question is whether I should hardwire the prefix to the bundle identifiers in the code too, in order to make them work on users' computers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turned out that this was my misunderstanding.

The prefix is the team identifier Apple assigns to every registered developer. It won't have effect on the bundle identifiers of your apps. Rather, one of the places impacted by it is the group identifier if you have deployed the app group in your project.